# Make a trail inside the bge

Tags: game-engine

I've tried do to draw a curve with the bge module, assuming I have a list of locations :

```
for i in range(1, len(positions) - 1):
    bge.render.drawLine(positions[i - 1], positions[i], (1, 0, 0))
```

But the following doesn't work at all. What is wrong with this ?
This is the piece of code I've written, and I'd like to be able to draw the trajectory of the object.

```
import bge

own = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
own["positions"] = []
own.applyForce((1, 1, 1), 0)
own["positions"].append(own.worldPosition)
for i in range(1, len(own["positions"]) - 1):
    bge.render.drawLine(own["positions"][i - 1], own["positions"][i], (1, 0, 0))
```

EDIT:

Changed the script according to Chebhou's answer:

```
import bge
own = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
if "positions" not in own :
    own["positions"] = []
own.applyForce((1, 1, 1), 0)
own["positions"].append(own.worldPosition.copy())
for i in range(1, len(own["positions"]) - 1):
    bge.render.drawLine(own["positions"][i - 1], own["positions"][i], (1, 0, 0))
```

Comment: what errors you are getting ?, how are saving the position ?

Comment: The trails are not shown at all.

Comment: position is cleared every logic tic, you are doing that with `own["positions"] = []`

Comment: I know. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

positions variable is being cleared at every execution of the script by the line `own["positions"] = []` to prevent this replace that line with :

```
if 'positions' not in own :
    own["positions"] = []
```

---

***Edit :***
The position list was not extended properly it was taking pointers to the object position to fix this replace `own["positions"].append(own.position)` with `own["positions"].append(own.position.copy())`

Comment: Thank you. But I have an other problem : I can't plot the trail, although the locations are putted in the 'positions' list.

Comment: @user14219 see if this will work